# MySQL - avoid truncating trailing zeros in float datatype

Tags: mysql, floating-point, varchar

I've got a column for storing float data, i.e.

```
1.1
11.60
4.23
```

Unfortunately, `11.60` gets stored as `11.6`.  I need it to have that extra zero.  Do I have to change my datatype to varchar? What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Suggest that leading/trailing zeros are for the client to display, rather than for the database to store.

Comment: You could store it as a `DECIMAL(something, 2)` assuming you needed two decimal places on the right for all of the numbers, but your example doesn't support that theory.  If you really need the number to stay exactly as stored `VARCHAR` might be the way to go.

Comment: @p. campbell - understood, but it's a coded product system, so 11.6 is different than 11.60.

Comment: @mootinator - another successful mootination, I'll stick with varchar.

Comment: It almost looks like you have a Product_ID and a Sub_ID?

Comment: @Paul - yes, now that you mention that.  I suppose I should have two columns to handle that, eh? I'll probably do that. But the original question is still the same, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds from the comments that you're storing a product code, so float isn't a good choice for a datatype, as you suggest. Indeed it's not a rendering issue, but we'd misconstrued it from your initial choice of float (thinking you indeed were storing something like money or true decimal).

Go with varchar, as you suspected, as it really is a string value.

Here's how you can do that:

- create a new column of type varchar(100) or whatever length is suitable for you
- copy the values into the new column from your float column

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD MyNewColumn VARCHAR(100);

UPDATE MyTable
SET MyNewColumn = FORMAT(MyFloatColumn, 2);
```

Comment: @p. campbell - see comments at Bohemian (basically the same solution).  However, since I'm ultimately using the varchar solution, I'll give you the accept.  Thanks to all for the tips.

Comment: @Steve : right, formatting the float to 2 decimals might not be the best solution, as it won't really know if it needs to pad for 2, 5 or 10 trailing digits. Converting the data would be another trick you'd need to pull off.

Answer (score 2):

This is a *rendering* issue, not a *data* issue. To "solve" it, apply mysql's [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function to your value as you select it:

```
select FORMAT(my_float_column, 2)
from my_table;
```

The `2` is the number of decimal places. It will handle (almost) any number of digits to the left of the decimal place.

Comment: Bohemian and others - this looks like it would break on numbers longer than 2 digits...thoughts?